# How to inject one variable depends on two different use cases?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

The situation is that I need to inject one variable in my Activity (it will be ViewModel), on which I can go from two different button pushes:

- orange button - is subtraction
- green button - is addition

[image]

It doesn't matter which button we push, both lead us to another activity, but the ViewModel will do different work depending on the button.

I would likt to know a valid approach on how to put a flag in the constructor or maybe other options.

Here is my code (BaseActivity):

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    initDIComponent();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    applicationComponent = getApplicationComponent();
}

/**
 * Get the Main Application component for dependency injection.
 *
 * @return {@link com.denis.mypocket.internal.di.components.ApplicationComponent}
 */
public ApplicationComponent getApplicationComponent() {
    return ((MyPocketApp) getApplication()).getApplicationComponent();
}

/**
 * Get an Activity module for dependency injection.
 *
 * @return {@link com.denis.mypocket.internal.di.modules.ActivityModule}
 */
protected ActivityModule getActivityModule() {
    return new ActivityModule(this);
}
```

Activity with ViewModel:

```
public class AddTransactionActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Inject
public AddTransactionViewModel viewModel;
private ActivityAddTransactionBinding binding;
private boolean isIncome = false;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    isIncome = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(PLConstants.INTENT_INCOME_FLAG,false);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_add_transaction);
    binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
    binding.addTrans.setOnClickListener(viewModel.addOnClick);
    configireToolbar(binding.toolbarAddTrans.toolbar, R.string.toolbar_add_trans, true);
}


@Override
protected void initDIComponent() {
     DaggerAddTransactionComponent.builder()
            .applicationComponent(getApplicationComponent())
            .activityModule(getActivityModule())
            .build().inject(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Module` is used to provide dependencies. If you reuse the same acitvity with 2 different usecases, the Module is the thing you need to change.

Just add an `int` or `enum` parameter to your Module constructor and pass in the type (addition or subtraction) to use. To retrieve the type you would just write and read it from your intent extras.

Since you seem to be using the same `BaseModule` for all of your activities you would probably want to create another module for that.

Comment: few minutes ago I add a boolean field in the module, and pass it to viewModel, but thanks anyway!